# Do student loans capitalize daily after the grace period?

Tags: united-states, loans, interest, student-loan

As I understand it, for many student loans, when you take out the loan, there is a daily, fixed, simple interest that accrues. This accrues on the principal but does not capitalize. Therefore, if I am in school for 3 academic years, upon graduating, I then owe

Total = P + r_{daily}*P * 2.75 * 365

2.75 because I graduate in June.

After I graduate, I have a 6 month grace period during which interest continues to accrue but does not capitalize. So it's the same thing. If I still don't pay anything, when the grace period ends, I owe

Total = P + r_{daily}*P * 3.25 * 365

where the 3.25 comes from the additional 6 months. Let's suppose I couldn't pay my loans up to this point, perhaps because I couldn't find work. Now I get happen to get a job right at the end of this grace period. But too late, it ends and my interest gets capitalized.

So now future interest is calculated based on Total = P + r_{daily}*P * 3.25 * 365 instead of just P.

Now suppose my job isn't very good and I can't quite cover my interest payments. Would my daily accrual now capitalize daily as well?

I know this is all very speculative, but the point I was trying to understand was, does capitalization of loans only happen once or does it happen daily after the grace period is over?

I am using two types of loans

- Direct Unsubsidized Loans:
  https://studentaid.gov/understand-aid/types/loans/subsidized-unsubsidized
- Grad Plus:
  https://studentaid.gov/understand-aid/types/loans/plus/grad

Any clarification on this would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unsubsidized loans will capitalize once after the grace period and then capitalize/compound periodically (most likely monthly) if you do not pay at least the interest portion.

I have never seen a loan that compounds *daily* - most likely it will compound monthly. However, even a loan that compounds daily would not be significantly worse than one that compounds monthly.

For example, if you had a balance of $10,000 at 5%, the balance after 1 year with daily compounding would be

```
10,000 * (1+.05/365)^365 = 10,512.67
```

versus monthly compounding:

```
10,000 * (1+.05/12)^12   = 10,511.62
```

or a difference of 0.01%

If you have unsubsidized loans, paying off the interest while you are in school will have a much greater impact than the compounding period.

If you are taking out student loans and aren't certain that you can get a job that will cover them, I would strongly recommend NOT taking out loans - find a school that you can afford to pay without loans, or choose a field of study that mas more certain job prospects. Having student loans over your head without the ability to pay them back will be a huge burden that will stay with you for many years.